# Do I need a new ISBN when I change an illustration within my existing published book?

Tags: self-publishing, first-time-author, isbn

I published my picture book with an ISBN. I own the ISBN. Post publication I realized a character pose, on a page, does not represent the emotion, on the page. If I update the character pose and republish do I need to assign it a new ISBN?

The book was published in April of this year. I have had 20 sales in all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I need a new ISBN?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/20869/when-do-i-need-a-new-isbn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think about this from the perspective of someone buying your book: When I buy your book, thinking I'll get the newest version, and I get the old version instead of the new one, would I feel cheated? Then your book needs a new ISBN.